# Wordpress Permalinks & Apache not found or unable to stat, referer

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am trying to get a copy of a Wordpress site spun up in my local environment and the home page loads correctly, but when I attempt to load a link from the menu I get a 404.

1. I have given ownership to www-data, and set folders and files to 755 & 644.
2. I have the default .htaccess in place.
3. apache.conf is set so the directory AllowOverwrite is set to ALL

So now when I look at the apache log I see this entry just after loading a page that results in a 404...

```
[php7:error] [pid 6427] [client ::1:53910] script '/home/my-user/development/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/my-wordpress-site/
```

Comment: Did you run through the database and amend all the urls that are kept in the database? Thats the normal hiccup with moving WP sites

Comment: Can you check if [`AccessFileName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#accessfilename) is set to `.htaccess`? Should be default, but if it isn’t, Apache will not care for the .htaccess. Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did a global fid and replace and replaced `my-wordpress-site.wpengine.com` with `localhost/my-wordpress-site`

Comment: @misorude all this checks out

Comment: _“I have the default .htaccess in place.”_ - that might not do, if you have WP running in a folder, and not at root domain level. If you can reach your admin dashboard, then flush the permalink settings from there (simply save the settings once again), then WP should update the .htaccess itself (provided it is writable.)

Comment: @misorude if you put this as an answer, this worked perfectly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the default .htaccess in place.

That might not do, if you have WP running in a folder, and not at root domain level.

Flush the permalink settings in the admin dashboard (simply save the settings once again), then WP should update the .htaccess itself – provided it is writable.